# How to refresh div content without loading file?

Tags: javascript, php

I have simple PHP file:

#### Javascript code:

```
<script src="jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
     $('#links').fadeOut("slow").load("test.php").fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000);

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

</script>
```

#### Needed element:

```
<p>Date sended: <span id="links"><?=dateDiff("2018-01-13 13:26")?></span></p>
```

#### PHP code:

```
<?php
    function dateDiff($date1, $date2 = false)
    {   
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dushanbe");
        if($date2 == false) $date2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $date_1 = new DateTime($date1);
        $date_2 = new DateTime($date2);

        $diff = $date_1->diff($date_2);

        if ($diff->days > 365) {
            return $date_1->format('Y-m-d');
        } elseif ($diff->days > 7) {
            return $date_1->format('M d');
        } elseif ($diff->days > 1) {
            return $date_1->format('l - H:i');
        } elseif ($diff->days == 1) {
            return "Yesterday ".$date_1->format('H:i');
        } elseif ($diff->days > 0 OR $diff->h > 1) {
            return $date_1->format('H:i');
        } elseif ($diff->i >= 1) {
            return $diff->i." min ago";
        } elseif ($diff->d == 0 AND $diff->s < 60) {
            return $diff->s." sec ago";
        } else {
            return "Just now";
        }
    }
?>
```

Here I use path to file in `load()` method. And I now copied my php function to current document. Can I use emty `load()` method and refresh needed div content every 5 seconds without another file?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of your html and jquery and php code in a same file. But add a querystring to the URL to say if you are looking for update or the main content. if the act is update then clear the page using `ob_end_clean();` to receive only requested update. also use `exit()` immediately after that to stop other processing.

OK. First add query string `act=update` to the load url:

```
 $('#links').fadeOut("slow").load("test.php?act=update").fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000);
```

second: updated the php code to eliminate other html and jquery code and just run the php part of page:

```
<?php
ob_start();
if (isset($_GET["act"])){

if ($_GET["act"]=='update'){
ob_end_clean();

    function dateDiff($date1, $date2 = false)
    {   
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dushanbe");
        if($date2 == false) $date2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $date_1 = new DateTime($date1);
        $date_2 = new DateTime($date2);

        $diff = $date_1->diff($date_2);

        if ($diff->days > 365) {
            return $date_1->format('Y-m-d');
        } elseif ($diff->days > 7) {
            return $date_1->format('M d');
        } elseif ($diff->days > 1) {
            return $date_1->format('l - H:i');
        } elseif ($diff->days == 1) {
            return "Yesterday ".$date_1->format('H:i');
        } elseif ($diff->days > 0 OR $diff->h > 1) {
            return $date_1->format('H:i');
        } elseif ($diff->i >= 1) {
            return $diff->i." min ago";
        } elseif ($diff->d == 0 AND $diff->s < 60) {
            return $diff->s." sec ago";
        } else {
            return "Just now";
        }

exit();
}
}

?>
```

You dont need to initialize the content inside the span. Instead you have to know the initial value that should be passed to the update function. I suggest using data tag like this:

```
<p>Date sended: <span id="links" data-initialdate="2018-01-13 13:26"></span></p>
```

and in every call, send it to compare:

```
var baseTime=$('#links').data("initialdate");
  $('#links').fadeOut("slow").load("test.php?act=update&date1="+baseTime).fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000);
```

In this scenario you have to change your function to read the date1 from php get not as an input of function.

Comment: can I call php function from current document not usage another document. I not need use in load() method link to another file @Ali Sheikhpour

Comment: The code I wrote are totally in same file name it test.php. Both jquery and php are in same file but you can decide if you are looking for html and jquery part or php part by using the querystring that I suggested above.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more details. Please read again

Comment: If I will paste my php function in to block if then if I call it here `<p>Date sended: <span id="links"><?=dateDiff("2018-01-13 14:09")?></span></p>` given php error `Undifined function`

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dateDiff() in D:\OSPanel\domains\hash.loc\index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\OSPanel\domains\hash.loc\index.php on line 16`

Comment: I put the function inside if else because I thought you just want to use it on updates. You said nothing about other parts of your page. If you want to use same function `dateDiff()`  to initialize the content of  the page, you can do that by same ajax load() or totally put the `dateDiff()` function outside of if-then. So you can call it both outside and inside of `if-then`.

Comment: Also You have to pass the initial date to the function when you call the load(). Please update your question and say what date you want to pass to the function to compare? the current time?

Comment: Yes current date

Comment: I have list messages I I'll display it in loop and I every 5-10 sec must update only sended date using javascript generaly

Comment: Difference from sended date of messages and current time. Refresh must be refresh real time with out take parameters to GET by user click

Comment: OK. I have updated the answer by more details at the end. Please note that the datediff function should be changed according to what I explained.

Comment: the above doesn't output anything as the function doesn't get called and nothing is echoed back

Comment: Sorry. I have changed the initial data-tag to a simple date not the output of datediff function.

Comment: probably want to urlencode what you're sending `"test.php?act=update&date1="+encodeURI(baseTime)` --- also in my test it wasn't necessary to use ob_start or ob_end_clean

Answer (score -1):

```
function refreshId() {
    $('#links').fadeOut("slow").load("test.php").fadeIn("slow");
}

var run = setInterval(refreshId, 5000);
```

Comment: I not need call function in `load()` method from another file